# Do 3D objects have perimeter?

Tags: 3d

I have tried reading on it however got conflicting information. There are some sources that say that 3D objects don't have a perimeter. It's only applicable to 2D objects. However in other sources I have seen people trying to calculate perimeter of a cube(3D) by measuring the length of each connecting line and adding them up.

Comment: A surface in 3D has a perimeter. A volume has not.

Comment: Polyhedra have a natural definition of perimeter that is the sum of the lengths of the edges.